# Graphic interpretation of a tensor

Tags: vectors, tensors, tensor-rank

The definition of a tensor of rank *n* in a three dimensional space is an array of $3^n$ values.

Therefore a tensor of rank $n=1$ in 3D space is a vector (made of three values, each corresponding to a value along axis defined by basis vectors), making a sample vector:

$$V = (1,2,3)$$

possible to interpret graphically as:

[image: Vector interpreted graphically]

So far, so good. Now if I have a sample tensor of rank $n=2$ defined in a 3D space:

$$T=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 1 \\
        3 & 4 & 0 \\
        5 & 3 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

What would be its interpretation on 3D graph?

Answer (score 1):

The vector space of rank $k$ tensors on an $n$-dimensional real vector space $V$ has dimension $n^k$, so you could visualize a rank $k$ tensor on $V$ as an arrow in $\mathbb{R}^{n^k}$.

However, thinking of a tensor (or what physicists mean by tensor) as an array of numbers isn't a very enlightening perspective.  Sure, you can define a tensor by specifying its components, but this perspective doesn't help you understand what it's used for. Think of a rank $k$ tensor $\phi$ on a real vector space $V$ as a multilinear map $\phi: V \times V \times \cdots \times V \to \mathbb{R}$. That is, a tensor of rank $k$ takes $k$ vectors from $V$ as inputs, and is separately linear in each slot.